# FireFox warning "Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'hidden' " keeps running over and over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently have discovered a warning happening in Firefox that says

> **Warning:** Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'hidden'

Here is page http://eleven23.net/eleven23/beta/work/web/lounge22.php

And the warning happens when it gets to the part of javascript that has img:hidden

> $('img:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn(500);//fades in the hidden images one by one
>               i++;//add 1 to the count

So Im wondering if anyone has an idea on how to resolve this warning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to really stop the repeated calling of `doThis()` via `setInterval` which at the moment doesn't happen. Thus the warning appears every 500ms.

Change

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  var int = setInterval("doThis(i)",500);
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  int = setInterval("doThis(i)",500);
});
```

Else your call to `clearInterval(int)` won't do anything as you declared `var int` twice and try to clear the "outer" int which isn't the interval.

After this fix only 4-5 of this warning should remain in your console.

---

Now to your error. There isn't much you can do to stop this error from appearing exactly that many times you call `doThis()`.

jQuery uses Sizzle internally as selector engine. And in some cases Sizzle tries to use (on browsers supported) the [`querySelectorAll()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) function to find the elements matching your selector.

Now AFAIK is `hidden` not a valid CSS selector thus although Firefox supports the call to `querySelectorAll()` it correctly fails after encountering an unknown selector. jQuery catches the error and then does the selection of `image:hidden` itself.

If you don't want to see this error at all you can use a different jQuery syntax which in this case would stop Sizzle from trying to attempt to use `querySelectorAll()`.

Change

```
$('img:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn(500);
```

to

```
$('img:hidden', $('div#content_wrapper')).eq(0).fadeIn(500);
```

But I don't advise you to do this as it doesn't really get you much only 4-5 warnings less in your console.

Comment: Thank you, I employed this strategy even though it still reports 4-5 warnings. This is a much better solution then allowing it to run every 500ms!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug within JQuery itself. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden

Check firebug, even on their example page you get this same warnring. It referes to a non-existing CSS pseudo-class :hidden. Where you are using `$('img:hidden')`