# Is eq the correct selector to get the first element of a jquery list? It gives me an error

Tags: jquery, selection

I try to get the first .myClass element of my page.

To do that, I use `$(".myClass:eq(0)");` This is working perfectly but gives me the following console error:

`"Warning: Pseudo-class or pseudo-element "eq" unknown."` (Traduced from french)

Is that error normal? Is there a way to avoid it? Which syntax do you use to select first elements? I also tried `$(".myClass:first");` but the problem is then the same with first.

Thank you in advance for your help
David

Comment: Is this "warning" or an error? I mean, is the code following this still working?

Comment: Thank you for the precision.
I use last version 1.4.2, downloaded yesterday. So I guess this error isn't normal?

Comment: @Felix - You got it wrong `The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0)` http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ ...You, misinterpreted it with `firt-child` ...

Comment: Do you guys have this warning? Is there another way to get the first element? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and correct. I'm wondering which jQuery version you are using and on what browser you are testing.

```
$(".myClass").first()
```

which is a shortcut for

```
$(".myClass").eq(0)
```

might solve your trouble. [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) will not use `sizzle` to query elements, but uses array `slice` to reduce the set of matched elements.

Comment: That works perfectly with the first(). No warning anymore, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this warning because `eq()` is not a valid css selector...

you are getting the same with `:first` because the [`:first` pseudo-class is equivalent to `:eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector)..

and jQuery catches this warning, and then do the thing it needs to do with it...

just same with this [`:hidden`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836252/firefox-warning-unknown-pseudo-class-or-pseudo-element-hidden-keeps-running)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I understand better now.