# jquery issue with pseudo class

Tags: jquery, pseudo-class

I have the following script inserted in an external file loaded after the jquery file. the code executes ok until the '.each' line

```
  $("form").submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 var msg = fx.init();
 alert($(':text').length);
 $('input:text').each(function()
 {
    if ($(this).val == 0)
    {alert('asd');
        msg.append ($(this).attr('id')+" does not have a value <br />");
    }

 })
```

});

the problem is that the 'alert' part is executed and it shows the correct number of elements, although when I look in Opera's Dragonfly Errors tab is shows the following messages:

> 1) "Unknown pseudo class Line 1: 
>   :text"   - this message is for the
>   'alert' line and
>
> 2) "Unknown pseudo
>   class Line 1:  input:text  - this
>   message is for the next line

I know I am a beginner but can any of you colleagues can see an error in this code?

the fx.init() is a small object at the top of the file to dynamically create the div into the page.

ps: this code was tested in both opera 11.10 and firefox 4 both with the same result

thank you in advance,
denis r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently jQuery's selector engine tries using browser functions before its own code, for speed. If a pseudo-selector isn't supported by a broswer, you get this warning. I'm not 100% sure about this, but [similar errors have been mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836252/firefox-warning-unknown-pseudo-class-or-pseudo-element-hidden-keeps-running). They're just warnings though, not errors, and AFAIK they don't interfere with anything.

As for your error, [val is a method](http://api.jquery.com/val/), so you need this:

```
if ($(this).val() == 0)
```

Comment: hi HertzaHaeon, thank you very much for the response..indeed the issue why the code was not executing is because I forgot the () for the val() function...it must have been the long hours :) weird though, is the fact that dragonfly did not mention that as an error at all. also the messages about pseudo class are still thrown but the code executes properly now, so for that I thank you.